# I keep Getting this Error Observable<{}> not assignable to Observable<Product> Angular 7

Tags: angular, observable, angular7

I am using Visual studio IDE for MAC, I can build the Angular 7 application but cannot run the app in browser. I am getting the error in the second method.**Observable<{}> not assignable to Observable**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../interfaces/product';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { shareReplay, flatMap, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
 })

export class ProductService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  private baseUrl: string = "/api/product/getproducts";

  private product$: Observable<Product[]>;

  /*This Method Works Fine */

  getProducts() : Observable<Product[]>
            {

               this.product$ = this.http.get<Product[]> 
               (this.baseUrl).pipe(shareReplay());
               return this.product$;

            }

        /*Error on this Method  */

  getProductById(id : number) : Observable<Product> 
            {
               return this.getProducts().pipe(flatMap(result => result), 
first(product => product.productId == id))
            }

                         }

export interface Product {
            productId?: number;
            name: string;
            description: string;
            outOfStock: boolean;
            price: number;
            imageUrl: string;
        }
```

Comment: I think your problem is `flatMap(result => result)`. First of all the `flatMap` operator is supposed to return an Observable while you are just returning the result which is of type `Product[]`. Having said that, I don't think you need the `flatMap` operator at all.

Comment: I tried removing flatMap() did not work, the error says getProducts() does not return Observable type Product, but it does return. It says Property name missing in '{}'

Comment: I think what you want is `this.getProducts().pipe(map(result => result.find(product => product.id === id))`. The `find` operator does not help you find an item within an array, it filters a sequence of events. But in your case you are making an HTTP request which will emit a single event containing an array.

Comment: Here's a StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhty2t

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for helping me , I used the code and most of the error is cleared only error I get now is Property find does not exist on type '{}' - do i have to import find as I see in Stackblitz, there was no import for it - could you advise

Comment: No import is required. `find` is part of the [JavaScript Array API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). For some reason it thinks that the events emitted by `getProducts` is of type `{}` instead of `Product[]`. From what you have posted I cannot see why you are experiencing this issue in your project.

Comment: Actually, that is the issue - the events emitted by getProducts is of type {} instead of Product[] and thats why I get the error, also in the previous code

Comment: So something must be different in the `getProducts` method between what you have in your project and what I have shown on StackBlitz.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `flatMap` to with an identity function to convert  `Observable<E[]>` to `Observable<E>`. Your code looks good having tested it on `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`. The suspect here is `getProducts()` and if it's returning `Observable<Product[]>` _i.e_ JSON array of products from the API service like you expect it to do.

Comment: Hi Guys, the issue is only caused in Visual studio IDE not in Visual studio Code - getProducts() does not contain the type Observable<Product[]>

Comment: Hello Guys, for those who have similar problems please update the mpm packages for rxjs and rxjs compact - this problem is then solved

Answer (score 1):

Per my comments to you question, changing your method to the following compiles successfully:

```
  getProductById(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    return this.getProducts().pipe(
      map(products => products.find(product => product.productId === id))
    );
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhty2t)

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for helping me , I used the code and most of the error is cleared only error I get now is Property find does not exist on type '{}' - do i have to import find as I see in Stackblitz, there was no import for it - could you advise